# NEST don't apply attribute mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I use nest 7.0.0 and asp.net core 2.2. i want to create indxe from poco class. in elasticsearch index create but without any mapping. create index method is :

```
public async Task CreateIndex()
{
  try
   {
    var getIndexResponse =await ElasticClient.Indices.GetAsync("myindex");
    if (getIndexResponse.Indices == null || !getIndexResponse.Indices.Any())
      {
        var createIndexResponse = await ElasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync("myindex", c => c
                                        .Map(p => p.AutoMap<MyModel>()));
      }
    }
   catch (Exception)
   {
   }
}
```

and MyModel is like this:

```
[ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = nameof(Id), RelationName = "MyModelMessage")]
public class MyModel
{
  [Number(NumberType.Long, Index = true, DocValues = false)]
  public long UserId { get; set; }

  [Date(Index = true)]
  public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

  [Text(Index = false)]
  public string ObjectName { get; set; }

  [Date(Index = true)]
  public DateTime UpdateAt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: when i debug code mapping is in "createIndexResponse" debug information and whit copy this and create index manually in Elasticsearch everything is Ok!

Comment: Which elasticsearch do you use? Value of `createIndexResponse.IsValid` is `true` or `false`?

Comment: i use elasticsearch 7.0.1 and value of `createIndexResponse.IsValid` is `true`!

Comment: Maybe index already exists so changes to mapping won't apply.

Comment: no i check there isn't exsists index already.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code against NEST 7.0.1 and elasticsearch 7.2.0 and mapping was created for the type:

```
class Program
{
    [ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = nameof(Id), RelationName = "MyModelMessage")]
    public class MyModel
    {
        [Number(NumberType.Long, Index = true, DocValues = false)]
        public long UserId { get; set; }

        [Date(Index = true)] public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [Text(Index = false)] public string ObjectName { get; set; }

        [Date(Index = true)] public DateTime UpdateAt { get; set; }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
        connectionSettings.DefaultIndex("documents");

        var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

        var getIndexResponse = await client.Indices.GetAsync("myindex");
        if (getIndexResponse.Indices == null || !getIndexResponse.Indices.Any())
        {
            var createIndexResponse = await client.Indices.CreateAsync("myindex", c => c
                .Map(p => p.AutoMap<MyModel>()));
            Console.WriteLine("index created");
        }
    }
}
```

and `http://localhost:9200/myindex/_mapping` returns:

```
{
  "myindex": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "createdAt": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "objectName": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": false
        },
        "updateAt": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "userId": {
          "type": "long",
          "doc_values": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is something missing?